# using DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

using core boilerplate framework 3.3.2 (latest doco i could see was for 3.2.1).

So i'm attempting to implement as db/tenant configuration.

To my delight I saw there was actually a class called `DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver` - fantastic!

In my `EntityFrameworkModule` I add to the `override PreInitialize()` method by adding the following line:

```
Configuration.ReplaceService<IConnectionStringResolver, DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

However this does not compile:

```
The non-generic method 'IAbpStartupConfiguration.ReplaceService(Type, Action)' 

cannot be used with type arguments  CCRE.EntityFrameworkCore
```

Hopefully somebody can set me on the right track...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following namespace:

```cs
using Abp.Configuration.Startup;
```

That accesses [this extension method](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/1eac7146a3f74ebefd8939318e812db87d76b8f7/src/Abp/Configuration/Startup/AbpStartupConfigurationExtensions.cs#L33-L41):

```cs
public static void ReplaceService<TType, TImpl>(this IAbpStartupConfiguration configuration, DependencyLifeStyle lifeStyle = DependencyLifeStyle.Singleton)
    where TType : class
    where TImpl : class, TType
{
    configuration.ReplaceService(typeof(TType), () =>
    {
        configuration.IocManager.Register<TType, TImpl>(lifeStyle);
    });
}
```

Comment: perfect - i can keep some more hair now